# Blurring A Dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, blur, android-dialog

I looked through forums and SO and find many examples on how to display a dialog with a blurred and dim background which I put in place in my app. The issue I have now is when I want to display a second dialog on top of the previous one but still keeping both on the screen. The effect I would like is to dim and blur the background a second time when the second pop-up shows up. But what it does at the moment is blurring the activity again and not blurring the dialog that is still showing in the background.

So my question would be, is it possible to blur a dialog, when opening another dialog? If yes how could I do this? (Make sure you read the question well... I know how to blur the activity, the question is how to blur the dialog already shown on screen when I open a new dialog on top of it....)

Thanks very much

Comment: How do you blur the activity? Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

you can create fullscreen dialog with custom layout which consist from
real dialog content and blurred transparent part outside which would blur and overlay all background views.

Comment: how would you blur the backgroudn views including the previous dialog? Are you proposing to take a screenshot of the screen before to open the pop-up and blur that screenshot and use this as backgrounf of the new dialog?